# in ruby/chef, what is the difference between "end if" and only_if"?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

In chef (therefor, ruby), I've seen two ways of declaring conditionals

```
resource 'foo' do
  echo "Ubuntu"
end if node['platform'] == 'ubuntu'
```

and

```
resource 'foo' do
  echo "Ubuntu"
  only_if node['platform'] == 'ubuntu'
end
```

Don't these effectively do the same thing?  In the official docs, it seems "only_if" is the preferred way, and I can't find many examples of the "end if", but just curious if they, as they seem, do the same thing (execute the block only if the conditional is true).

Thanks!

Comment: `end if` isn't a thing, per se. The code you've shown is equivalent to `resource('foo') { echo "Ubunutu" } if node['platform'] == 'ubuntu'`. Postfix `if` can be used on any expression.

Answer (score 2):

### Chef Resource Guard Clauses vs. Expression Post-Conditions

[only_if](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/opscode/chef/Chef/Resource%3Aonly_if) is a [guard clause](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common/#only_if-examples) that's part of the Chef DSL. However, `do...end if` is a Ruby [modifier control expression](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Modifier+if+and+unless) (sometimes called a post-condition) applied to a block that functions the same way a normal [Ruby if/then statement](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-if+Expression) works. Note that even though the `if` is placed after the expression to be evaluated, the post-condition is still evaluated *first*.

Think of `only_if` as a Chef-specific resource statement. The other is just syntactic sugar supported by Ruby's interpreter, and the example you cited (assuming it works in Chef outside a Ruby resource block; I didn't bother to test it) is the same as writing the block inside a more standard if-statement like this one:

```rb
if node['platform'] == 'ubuntu'
  resource 'foo' do
    echo "Ubuntu"
  end 
end
```

Most Chef resources should follow the current style guides and DSL features, but post-conditions are very common in idiomatic Ruby because they emphasize the expression rather than the conditional and because they allow for more brevity of code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference in how `only_if` and `end if` behave when a node is converged (in Chef speak). In simple terms, when `chef-client` starts, it compiles the cookbooks and creates a collection of resources that will converge on the node.

For the sake of example, let's say we have a cookbook `cookbook1` with only 1 resource in the recipe. When we run such cookbook in below scenarios:

**Scenario 1**:

Using `do .. end if`:

The resource is removed from the compilation when the condition is not matched. So there will be no resources to run. Example output from chef-client run when `node['platform']` *is not* `ubuntu`.

```
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 0 resources
```

**Scenario 2**:

Using `only_if` guard

The resource remains in the collection, but it is skipped when `node['platform']` *is not* `ubuntu`.

```
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 1 resources
Recipe: cookbook1::default
  * resource[foo] action run (skipped due to only_if)
```

In short, pure Ruby code, such as `if` conditions will run during "compile" phase itself. Chef resources run during the "converge" phase. See the [Chef Infra Client documentation](https://docs.chef.io/chef_client_overview/) for details.